# Passing A Sentence That Has Been Split Into Pieces - Out Of Bounds?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that takes the user's words, changes them, and then spits out the changed words. Currently, I am using the input, and splitting it using .split(" "). The program works for singular words but any time you have a phrase like: "my dude lets go party" you get this error:

```
my dude lets go party
['my', 'dude', 'lets', 'go', 'party']
In: my
my word: my dude lets go party
my word my dude lets go party
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-62-3118b5db1cd0>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/jack/Desktop/PythonProjects/code/dogsbody.py', wdir='/home/jack/Desktop/PythonProjects/code')

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/jack/Desktop/PythonProjects/code/dogsbody.py", line 48, in <module>
    print(wordSelector(fword=userInput))

  File "/home/jack/Desktop/PythonProjects/code/dogsbody.py", line 30, in wordSelector
    possibilities = Word(fword).synsets[0].lemma_names()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

This seems like my for loop is not recognizing that I split the sentence into separate pieces, which is odd due to the fact that when you print the splitted sentence it comes up with the items separated.

```
from textblob import Word

def wordScore(fword):
    ref = {'e': 1, 't' : 2, 'a' : 3, 'o' : 4, 'i' : 5, 'n' : 6, 's' : 7, 'r': 8, 'h' : 9, 'l' : 10, 'd' : 11, 'c' : 12, 
       'u': 13, 'm': 14, 'f': 15, 'p': 16, 'g': 17, 'w': 18, 'y': 19, 'b': 20, 'v': 21, 'k': 22, 'x': 23,
       'j': 24, 'q': 25, 'z': 26, "'": -10, '-': 30}

    score = 0
    for letter in fword:
        score += ref[letter]
    return score


def wordSelector(fword):
    print("my word: " + fword)
    bestReplacement = ""
    bestScore = 1000
    if(fword == " "):
        return " "

    print("my word " + fword)
    possibilities = Word(fword).synsets[0].lemma_names()
    for possibility in possibilities:
        tempScore = wordScore(fword=possibility)
        if(tempScore < bestScore):
            bestReplacement = possibility
            bestScore = tempScore
    return bestReplacement






userInput = input()

userWords = userInput.split(" ")
print(userWords)
for word in userWords:
    print("In: " + word)
    print(wordSelector(fword=userInput))
```

Comment: `.split()` function by default splits by a single space

Comment: It's "not recognizing that I split the sentence" because you pass the whole un-split phrase into your function: `wordSelector(fword=userInput)` -> `wordSelector(fword=word)`

Comment: (Also, as an aside, python style guidelines are to use snake_case for variable names; e.g. `user_input` rather than `userInput`)

Comment: G. Anderson, thanks that was what my problem was. If you post it as answer I'll mark it correct. Or should I delete my q, since its a silly error?